# Wikitude POI does not set location

Tags: javascript, xamarin.android, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

I'm started to work on AR with Wikitude. I try to develop an app for Android on Xamarin.

I use the source codes but while using POI I get "trying to find out where you are" error. I used everything. The Permissions are ok, gps is open, tried inside and outside. But it never works. Do I miss something but where? Can anyone help me, please ?

Comment: Did you implement some way to get the location and pass it to the Wikitude SDK? If not you should take a look at this: https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/setupguideandroidlocation.html#location

Comment: Well, thanks Alex. I've realized that i can get locations, I've different problem about accesibilty service.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. For me, the GPS doesn't provide latitude and longitude coordinates. I need to go to system Settings > Location and turn on the "Accelerated location".